# Boolean Logic A'B + AB'

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a fairly simple question that i cannot find an example of online. I understand that this can simplify to A^B but I have not yet covered that section. What is the correct value of the boolean expression (A'B + AB')?

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NOT+A+AND+B+OR+A+AND+NOT+B) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the symbol XOR (^) is a^b = a'b + ab', i.e. one or the other but not both must be true for the expression to be true.  Therefore there are no intermediate steps to convert between the two expressions. This is because a'b and ab' are prime implicants of the boolean function.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at the truth table

```
A   B   A'B   AB'    A'B + AB'
-----------------------------
0   0   0     0      0
0   1   1     0      1
1   0   0     1      1
1   1   0     0      0
```

This simply computes the xor of A and B.
and hence this is our answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another (not necessarily more simplified) way to define XOR is (A+B).(A'+B')

```
A   B  A+B   A'  B'  A'+B' (A+B).(A'+B')
----------------------------------------
0   0   0    1   1     1        0
0   1   1    1   0     1        1
1   0   1    0   1     1        1
1   1   1    0   0     0        0
```